# Windows 10 laptop with external monitor: does not wake from sleep with power button unless the lid is open?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I use Windows 10 laptop mostly with external monitor. When it goes to sleep I can't wake it up with the power button. I have to open the lid first, and then press the power button, then close the lid and continue working with external monitor.

Can this be fixed?

Also, when I send the laptop to sleep, the power button blinks. However, after some time it stops blinking and this is when I can't wake the laptop any more without opening the lid. Does this mean that there are two kinds of sleep, "blinking" shwallow sleep and "deep" sleep?

Comment: A monitor connected to a computer does not "wake up" until it receives the video signal. About sleep and other power options, you can set them in Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options. Take a look at this [guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2843-change-power-plan-settings-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: But why does it not wake when I press the laptop power button? This should wake it up and send the signal to monitor - but it does not.

Comment: Evidently the monitor does not receive the video signal until the lid is opened. Perhaps this can be changed in the power options settings.